Subtle mistake in conda create syntax will install a patch = 0 version of python
I'm creating a new conda environment with no additional packages.
It is interesting to note the difference in the python interpreter version installed with a small change in the conda create syntax...
conda create --name test python=3.11

...installs python 3.11.9 as expected.
However but putting a double == rather than a single = when specifying the python version...
conda create --name test python==3.11

...does not throw any errors but creates an environment containing python 3.11.0, not the 3.11.9 that I was expecting.
This is consistent across 3.9, 3.10, 3.11 and 3.12, all install patch version 0.
I assume the double == is not the correct syntax and that this is not an intended behaviour but this is not caught and certainly confused me for a while.
Windows 10, conda version 23.11.0

It is definitely desired behavior and not a bug: Specifying the version with = is considered a "fuzzy constraint" while == is considered an "exact constraint".
The Conda Cheat Sheet gives as an example:



Constraint type
Specification
Result




Fuzzy
numpy=1.11
1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.18 etc.


Exact
numpy==1.11
1.11.0



Similarly, as pointed out by @FlyingTeller, the section Conda Package Specification (subsection Command Line Match Spec Examples) of the conda documentation gives the following examples:



Example
Meaning




conda install numpy=1.11
The fuzzy constraint numpy=1.11 matches 1.11, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.18, and so on.


conda install numpy==1.11
The exact constraint numpy==1.11 matches 1.11, 1.11.0, 1.11.0.0, and so on.



Arguably, this could be better documented with the commands themselves, such as conda create and conda install, where, at the time of writing, no such documentation can be found.

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/package-spec.html#id3 also mentions how double and single = are handled, but I would also expect that the docs of conda install would mention it somehow

@FlyingTeller Indeed, I also found this. However, some lines above the table it states "This match specification is not the same as the syntax used at the command line with conda install" (emphasis by me). So, in a way, it only says it's not the same, but it does not say in which way it differs from the conda install version specification syntax.

True, also confused me. Further down, it has this table which I guess is the basis for the cheat-sheet

@FlyingTeller Oh, I did not see that one! This table makes more sense. If you don't mind, I will add the link to my answer.

Thanks all, this looks pretty conclusive so I will accept answer.
